# How to emulate concurrent SQL commands using the shell

Tags: mysql, shell

I hava a table, e.g. `stock`:

```
SELECT * FROM stock;
+------------+----------+
| product_id | quantity |
+------------+----------+
|          1 |      100 |
+------------+----------+
```

I want to mock concurrent submitting order and meantime reduce stock:

```
UPDATE store SET quantity = quantity-${count} WHERE product_id = ${product_id}
```

I want to know if this SQL is thread safe. I just use below manner to mock concurrent operations:

```
for ((i=0; i<100; i++))
do
    mysql -uroot -p123456 test -e "update stock set quantity=quantity-1 where product_id = 1" >/dev/null &
done
```

Then check if the final quantity is 0.
I want to know if this manner is right? That is, would it correctly send concurrent SQL command just as if 100 users submit a order at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good approach:

```
for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do
    mysql -uroot -p123456 test -e "update stock set quantity=quantity-1 where product_id = 1" >/dev/null &
done

wait
```

You need the `wait` at the end to make it not exit while the jobs are still running.

Answer (score 0):

you can use stored procedure, or function. 
if the process is sequential like that.

or more advanced step using combine mysql store procedure + php + apache benchmark.
the apache benchmark has capability to spawn multiple process at once to simulate server load.
have multiple stored procedure to run at once to simulate not only stock reduction but also stock addition. and can also combine those reduction or addition with random number.

that way, you will have more reliable simulation rather than just a simple loop wich is a single thread scenario

Comment: but I think you are right, because the sql is very fast to execute , so actually it's serialized